# Magento - My block is not being displayed for some reason

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have tried doing it by following [guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/how_to_create_a_featured_product)

I have done everything exactly the same way, except I added:

```
<?php echo $this->getFeaturedProductHtml()?>
```

instead of

```
<?=$this->getFeaturedProductHtml()?>
```

in view.phtml

I have checked exception.log and system.log but there's nothing to be found in those files.

I have gone through lots of things, however I'm not experienced and lack knowledge how to debug / look for solution in magento environment.

Comment: Just a stupid question probably, but did you set some products "featured" and did you flush your cache?

Comment: Yes, there are two products set as featured and the cache is disabled

Comment: Do you have your logging enabled?

Comment: Yes, although there is nothing in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mage::log('debug text')` to see in which functions it comes. From there you can detect where the problem is. Alternative, you can just use the module from inchoo which is probably better and cleaner written: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-products-4605.html